# Images in another web application don't load until refresh

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I've just setup a new SharePoint site that has two web applications, one for MySites, and one with my main site collection in it.

For whatever reason whenever a users profile picture from MySites is displayed in a newsfeed or otherwise in my main site collection it doesn't load, however, if I refresh the page then it loads correctly. Is there something I can do to correct this?

Comment: Please use fiddler to see the request and response.

Comment: @BijuJoseph Could you provide some context on how to do this or is it fairly self explanatory? I'm not back in the office for another 12 hours, but I can look then.

Comment: What we do in such scenario is run fiddler and load web pages. After page load, do an analysis of the http traffic in the fiddler log.Fiddler can give you lots of information. Are you caching the images somewhere?

Comment: IE has similar functionality built in. Open IE then press F12, go to the Networking tab, press capture. Then load the page in question. You will be able to easily see the HTTP requests and any failure codes that might be returned by the other web application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you set the [SPWebApplication.CrossDomainPhotosEnabled](http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-enabling-cross-domain-profile-pictures) property?

```
asnp Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://intranet.contoso.com
$wa.CrossDomainPhotosEnabled = $true
$wa.Update()
```

Comment: Not at all, I didn't know about this! I'll try this first thing.

Comment: This worked perfect. I'll award the bounty as soon as it lets me!